Derivation of Einstein-Cartan (EC) action for parametrized connection $A$ & introduction of torsion
I have some trouble with one missing step when I want to get the teleparallel action from general EC theory, which I am not fully understanding.
The starting form of action (3-Dimensional) is:
$$
S_{EC}=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_M <e \wedge F[A]>
$$
for $$F[A]=dA+\frac{1}{2}[A,A]$$ where $<X_I,Y^I>$ is the killing form for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, while frame field is $e$ with the parametrized connection $A=\omega + \Delta$ for reference connection $\omega$ and difference tensor $\Delta$.
In what follows, $F[A]$ is expanded via parametrization in terms of fiducial reference connection $\omega ^I_a$ and displacement vector $\Delta^I_a$ leading to the strength tensor of the $SU(2)$ field:
$$F[A]=F[\omega]+ D_\omega\Delta+ \frac{1}{2}[\Delta,\Delta]$$ where $D_\omega=d + [\omega, .]$ is the exterior covariant derivative wrt reference connection ($\omega$).
When I plug it into the action, I get:
$$S_{EC}=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_M <e \wedge F[A]>=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_M <e\wedge F[\omega]+e\wedge D_\omega \Delta + \frac{1}{2}e\wedge[\Delta , \Delta].$$
While I can associate the $$ \frac{1}{2}e\wedge[\Delta , \Delta]=\frac{1}{2}e\wedge[\Delta \wedge \Delta],$$ I am encountering some issues with the second term in the action, ie $e\wedge D_{\omega}\Delta$. Expanding this term in terms of $d$ and Lie bracket, I have:
$$e\wedge D_{\omega}\Delta=e\wedge d\Delta+e\wedge [\omega,\Delta].$$
Then, the Leibnitz rule i.e. $$d(e\wedge \Delta)=d e \wedge \Delta - e \wedge d \Delta$$  (since $\Delta$ is 1-form) allows me to get rid of the $d \Delta$ term:
$$e\wedge D_{\omega}\Delta=-d(e\wedge \Delta)+d e\wedge \Delta+e\wedge [\omega,\Delta].$$
Now, I want to implement the torsion wrt. $\omega$ which is given by $^{\omega}T=de + [\omega,e]=D_\omega e$ in order to get the final action of:
$S_{\mathrm{EC}}[e,A] = S_{\mathrm{EC}}[e,\Delta;\omega]
=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\mathcal{M}}\Big<e\wedge F[\omega]-d(e\wedge\Delta)+^{\omega}{T}\wedge \Delta+\frac{1}{2}e\wedge[\Delta\wedge\Delta]\Big>$.
However, my current expression is:
$S_{\mathrm{EC}}[e,\Delta;\omega]
=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\mathcal{M}}\Big<e\wedge F[\omega]-d(e\wedge\Delta)+d e\wedge \Delta+e\wedge [\omega,\Delta]
+\frac{1}{2}e\wedge[\Delta\wedge\Delta]\Big>$.
So, In order to obtain the correct action I have to replace somehow $e\wedge [\omega,\Delta]$ by $[\omega,e]\wedge \Delta$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed any further - perhaps there is some identity that says $[\omega,e]\wedge \Delta=e\wedge [\omega,\Delta]$ or some form of relation that turns Lie bracket into the wedge product?
Here is the reference that I am trying to follow:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02801

Your action $S_{EC}=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_M <e \wedge F[A]>$ is a 3-form. Are you talking about 3D gravity? For 4D, you formula is not correct, since we need 4-form for 4D.

yeah, it is 3d gravity. I have added info about dimensionality of the action in the original post for clarification
